# Why is my Symfony2 texarea rendering as a single-line text field?

Tags: forms, symfony

I've got a Symfony2.0 form and am trying to add a textarea field, by setting the field type to [textarea](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/textarea.html).

If I pick anything else - number, percentage or whatever - it renders correctly.  However, my textareas are rendering as single-line textboxes.

Any ideas why this could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was with my [form theming](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#form-theming).  This wasn't obvious, as I didn't have anything in my `form_layout.twig` about textareas.

However, I *was* specifying `{% block text_row %}` in there.  It turned out that textarea field display was falling back to using `text_row` because I hadn't also included a definition for `{% block textarea_row %}`.  Once I added the missing block, everything worked as expected.